# Nebular flip card - How to make card back height different from the card front height (Angular)

Tags: css, angular, height, nebular

Nebular card front and back have the same height as the side with the most amount of content (if card front has 20 lines of text, and card back has 10 lines, there will be an empty 10 lines of space in card back as to keep it evenly sized with card front). How can I customize the sizes of the heights so that card back and card front have their own unique, predetermined heights?

```
<nb-flip-card [showToggleButton]="false" [flipped]="flipped">


  <nb-card-front>
    <nb-card>
      <nb-card-body>
        <app-home></app-home>
      </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
  </nb-card-front>


  <nb-card-back >
    <nb-card >
      <nb-card-body>
        <app-about></app-about>
      </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
  </nb-card-back>

</nb-flip-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure the amount of content that will be in the largest side (i.e. it isn't dynamic content being loaded) You can use `<br>` or `margin` styles to push the other side to match. I have also used max-height but that is not always preferable.

It is an annoying part of the flip card that doesn't have a resolution yet from Nebular. It would be nice if the smaller side would pull content below the card up to it.